# detect file handle conflict in windows

Tags: windows, file, filesystems, handle

Operations like deleting an opened file cause a file handle conflict. If I need to detect such file handle conflicts, is the filter driver(or minifilter drivers) the only option?

Comment: Detecting it is simple, ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION when you try to open the file.  Finding the name of the process that has the file opened is not, a driver is required to poke the undocumented internal handle tables.  Like SysInternals' Handle utility does.

Comment: I mean writing an daemon process that can detect such file conflicts,how is that process gonna be alerted of such conflicts,and finding the conflicting process

Answer (score 1):

That I think you're asking for is: I have a daemon that has opened a file. When another process wants to get access to the file, I want the daemon to be notified and allow him to close the file, if possible, to allow the other process to continue.  This requires the daemon to make use of "oplocks".  See the MSDN documentation on oplocks.